# Cannot find type in Scope using CoreData with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Using this code which compiles and seems to run ok as I can tap the add button and create new items) I get an error showing in Xcode. How do I get rid of the annoying error?

I have tried deleting the build folder, restarting Xcode to no avail.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Medicine> // Cannot find type ‘Medicine’ in scope
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text("Start at \(item.start!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            HStack {
                EditButton()
                Spacer()
                Button(action: addItem, label: {
                    Text("Add")
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check entity properties in the `.xcdatamodeld` file. `Codegen` should probably be set to `Class Definition` and `Module` to `Current Product Module`.

Comment: They already were set, still same problem

Comment: I had the problem. It was the pre-compiler that was given false info. The build passed successfully and the run too.

Comment: Can you answer your question? I get the same issue. I've tried adding `entity: example.entity` to the fetchRequest

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out, this is a pre-compiler issue which you will notice in your editor.

After you make sure that the `.xcdatamodeld` file is **saved** and that its `Codegen` property is set to `Class Definition`, you should be able to just build (Product -> Build or ⌘-B).

Another caveat: look at any possible additional error messages. In my case, I had inadvertently added an attribute to an entity (I guess a slip of mouse) which had no type (such as String, Int16, etc.). This error prevented the data model file from being processed and produced the "cannot find in scope" error. Fixing the data model also fixed the downstream error.